# how to connect to wifi programmatically using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Using xamarin forms, is it possible to create an app that connects/disconnects to a wifi AP ? I am trying to avoid creating an iOS and Android project since my UI requirements are pretty simple.

Comment: I know it's bad to share links but here        https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/02/15/connecting-wifi-xamarin-forms/

Comment: thank you a lot! it seems that it what I was looking for

Comment: cool, I posted this as an answer, if you could mark as an answer.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's bad to share links but here

[spin.atomicobject.com/2018/02/15/connecting-wifi-xamarin-forms](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/02/15/connecting-wifi-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Hello, just wanted to ask if there's a way to also show a list of networks where you can connect it to?

Comment: If you look in that article it mentions "We will use it to add a new network to the device’s list of configured networks" so it sounds like its possible

Comment: ? Have you seen any links of solution for both iOS and Android?

Comment: I believe with both native implementations in the article you can list out the available wifi networks